# Install BootCamp drivers in Windows 10 to fix bluetooth and keyboard issues

Tags: keyboard, windows, bootcamp, bluetooth, driver

I recently installed Windows 10 20H2 along with MacOs on my MacBook Pro, but upon booting Windows I can see the touchbar doesn't work in Windows(doesn't display anything), and Windows isn't detecting the Bluetooth hardware. I downloaded Windows Support software from bootcamp and tried to install it manually in Windows. But I am facing these errors:

[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Is there anyway I can manually install drivers?? I also checked on Windows Update but there was no driver updates there either.

My mac OS is on Big sur latest version and Windows is on 20H2.

## Update 1

If I force install `BootCamp.msi` by `msiexec /i BootCamp.msi` I get this error:

[image]

## Update 2

Turns out the issue was with the pendrive I downloaded the support software on, using a different pendrive solved the issue. However I am surprised with the poor Trackpad support with no additional multi-finger gestures and also the scrolling is inverted. Can I use precision driver instead of Apple's driver?

Comment: To avoid problems, the best solution is to use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10 on your Mac. You have given not any indication why you have not done this. You should edit your question and at least explain why you felt the need to install using some unexplained method.

Comment: Try adding `/qb-` to the msiexec call to suppress these boxes.  I used this to install Boot Camp 6.1 to my 2011 iMac so it would restart to APFS volumes.  See this brigadier PR for discussion of various options tried (you may have to try other `/q` options depending on version of bootcamp you are trying to install but `/qb-` as found in current in brigadier source on github worked for me) : https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier/pull/14 Worst case read the MS doc for msiexec: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search in [RocketDrivers](https://rocketdrivers.com/manufacturers/intel/bluetooth-devices/microsoft-bluetooth-enumerator) or other websites.

For the Touch Bar issue, just try to manually update the driver in Device Manager for each unrecognized device and see if it works.

A Touch Bar driver will be found in the Apple Boot Camp driver folder.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have one of the very early Intel Macs, the Windows Support Software is suppose to be available to the Windows installer during the installation process. This is so the Windows installer can access any drivers included in the Windows Support Software that are not already part of the installation software provided by Microsoft.

If you have an older Mac and are using the current Windows 10 release, then most likely any required drivers in the Windows Support Software will be already included in the Windows 10 release. In this case, having the Windows Support Software available to the Windows installer during the installation process may not be necessary.

Once Widows is installed, additional software can be installed by executing the `Setup.exe` application included in Windows Support Software. Afterwards, additional software can be installed through the `Apple Software Update` application. Windows Update may also provide software.

> Your question indicates you downloading the Windows Support Software after installing Windows. You can post a comment, if I am wrong about this.

My best guess would be you used the Boot Camp Assistant on a Mac of a different year and/or model to download the Windows Support Software. This is a common mistake. If you did this, then most likely the wrong Windows Support Software was downloaded.

The other possibility is your Mac Pro is older than the 2013 model. In this case, Apple does not support Windows 10 for your Mac. If this is true, then you should have included this in your question.

> The fact that you do not mention running `Setup.exe`, but instead mention `BootCamp.msi`, indicates that you did run `Setup.exe` which terminated early with an error message. The message either states lack of support for Windows 10 or you have the wrong version of Boot Camp.